# Chromecast MediaTrack

Tags: android, chromecast

How can I load a subtitle to chromecast Media player?

```
List<MediaTrack> subs = new ArrayList<MediaTrack>();
... MediaTrack.Builder(long trackid, MediaTrack.TYPE_TEXT);
```

I dont know how to get trackid....

EDIT:

```
long subId = 12;
long[] subIds = {subId};
MediaTrack track = new MediaTrack.Builder(subId,MediaTrack.TYPE_TEXT).setContentId("http://example.com/abc.srt").build();
    subs.add(track);
...
mediaInfo.setMediaTracks(subs);
...
mRemoteMediaPlayer.setActiveMediaTracks(mApiClient,subIds);
```

subtitles are not being shown

Answer (score 1):

According to new documentation - you have to set language to subtitle:

```
  MediaTrack englishSubtitle = new MediaTrack.Builder(1 /* ID */, MediaTrack.TYPE_TEXT)
  .setName("English Subtitle")
  .setSubtype(MediaTrack.SUBTYPE_SUBTITLE)
  .setContentId("https://some-url/caption_en.vtt")
  /* language is required for subtitle type but optional otherwise */
  .setLanguage("en-US")
  .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

`trackId` is something that you set on your tracks when you build them for your `MediaInfo`; it is a unique identifier that you set so later on you can refer to that track.

Comment: Are you using our Default/Styled receiver? What are you using as your sender? Did you remember to load the media after you had set the tracks? What does the chrome console log says? Did you enable CORS headers for both your media and closed tracks? More info is needed to be able to help you there.

Comment: Im using default receiver. My logcat says:
"Problem occurred with media during loading"
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: No current media session" when setActiveMediaTracks is called

Comment: I asked a number of questions but didn't get answer to most of them. Your log shows there is no current media session, so try to figure out why. You first need to load the media and then set the active track.